# Maven Package Range

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I want to check from before hand which package ranges my maven project will be used ?
I mean like npm package.json or like nuget publishes the nuget dependencies range.

I haven't seen a place. since pom.xml does not include ranges everytime for packages and is being resolved by maven version manager.
I saw this https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/display-dependency-updates.html
basically showing me the latest.
I want something like a >= 1.00 or b >= 1.0.0 <= 2.0.0
on my project

Comment: Can you explain more in detail what you exactly mean by: `which package ranges my maven project will be used `... and `since pom.xml does not include ranges everytime for packages `?

Comment: Yes, what I want to know is which version my direct maven packages support. Say I have direct packages(I.e pom.xml) a,b,c - a range can be from 1.0.0 to 2.0.0 b from 2.5.2 to 3.0.0 and c from 3.0.7 - 3.5.3 but I wouldn’t know that since I solved it using maven package resolver which probably resolves my project to the newest available. I want maybe to lock a version (if new version has vulnerabilities or I want the older api for performance etc). I know the practice says do not use ranges and let maven sort them out for you, i want to know according to which range does maven resolve packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With maven you can either use `mvn dependency:list` or `mvn dependency:tree` to show the project dependencies in a list or tree format.

And `mvn display-dependency-updates` to check for updates.

Answer (score 2):

In Maven, you don't use ranges for version numbers. The is actually a feature for this for dependencies, but it is considered bad practise.

Instead you regularly update the dependencies with the `versions` plugin. You can fine control this with parameters like `allowMajorUpdates`.

Comment: Yes, but can I tell the ranges in which it (the plug-in) can suggest for me? Look at my comment above. Say I wanna lock a certain version in that range is it possible?

Comment: If you have e.g. version `2.1.0` and you set `allowMajorUpdates` to false, then you will get the highest version of `2.x`. If you do not give a parameter, you get the highest overall version. I do not know what you mean by "locking". There is a version and you can update the version. There is no predefined range.

Comment: So how does maven knows ? Say a uses b and can only work with b 2.0.1 how does he account for it and where do I know this. Say in nuget for every nuget I see the package a supports version >= 2.0.0 so u know u can actually tell him get me only 2.0.1 and it satisfies this range. How does maven knows this for package b in this case. Or as u said I say only account for major update but the version supports only a specific version how does he resolves that ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want but maybe having a look to how Maven resolve dependencies would help. Consider looking for documentation about transitive dependencies and dependency management.

Comment: @ChenSho Maven knows nothing about compatible versions. You just set a version in your POM and then you see if it works.